# m3u8 video with dynamically generated <video> tag

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video, wowza

In a HTML5/JS app (backbone.js / jQuery) i'm having trouble embedding a `m3u8` video stream delivered by a `wowza` media server.

The app is supposed to run in mobile safari only, so the format would be allright.

The video gets embedded with a  tag, generated by Javascript.

```
<video src="http://someotherdomain.net:[customport]/path/playlist.m3u8" controls>
</video>
```

When embedding the video tag with a test stream-URL in a **static** test page, the video works perfectly up and down all tested iOS Versions.

**The Problem is when generating the tag with JS, the video stalls in loading state.**

Desktop Safari however plays the video just fine.

I couldn't figure out what's causing this so far. Could this be some security restriction on the mobile browser?

**UPDATE**

as this is some closed and rather complex app i'm unfortunately not able to provide a non-working example, but this is the method that renders the video tag into the page:

```
/**
 * add <video> tag and add source
 *
 * @param src
 */
loadVideoSource: function (src) {

    this.$el.find('video').remove();

    $('<video/>')
        .attr('src', src)
        .prop('autoplay', true)
        .prop('controls', true)
        .css('width', '100%')
        .css('height', '60%')
        .appendTo(this.$el.find('div.video'));

}
```

that port does work and renders the following `markup`:

```
<video 
    src="https://somedomain.com.tr:1935/live/12345678/playlist.m3u8" 
    autoplay 
    controls 
    style="width: 100%; height: 60%;"
></video>
```

i also tried initially having the video tag in the page an just adding the `src` attribute or `<source>` child.
I also tried to call `load()` and `play()` explicitly on the video element but that didn't help either...

Comment: hi can u share a part of js u have written may be a fiddle..

Comment: unfortunately not, but i updated the answer with a code snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after hours of debugging it simply turned out to be a CSS bug :P

Since you have to start a video explicitly in iOS, you'll have to press the play button in the video after loading the markup.

Strangely enough, this was prevented by

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

...which was used on the parent container of the video, and prevented the native play button of the video element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am posting a small snippet which i always use  for video..

```
videoElement = document.createElement('video'); // this audioelement is  used to create an audio tag
$(videoElement )
    .attr('id', 'video');

 function videoElement_Int_fn(currentPos) {

            var src = currentPos+'.mp4';

        videoElement .setAttribute('src', src);
        videoElement .load();
        videoElement .play();
}
```

Comment: how is this supposed to help with my question?

Comment: unfortunately creating the video tag that way, doesn't change the behaviour... thanks anyway, though !